# Convert Binary to Hex in Java using loop and switch

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner ms = new Scanner(System.in);

    String binary = ms.nextLine();
    binary=binary.trim();

    //add leading zeroes if length divided by 4 has remainder.
    while (binary.length() % 4 != 0) binary = "0" + binary;

    String number = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i += 4) {
       String num = binary.substring(i, i + 3);

       switch(num)
        {
            case "0000" : number = "0"; break;
            case "0001" : number = "1"; break;
            case "0010" : number = "2"; break;
            case "0011" : number = "3"; break;
            case "0100" : number = "4"; break;
            case "0101" : number = "5"; break;
            case "0110" : number = "6"; break;
            case "0111" : number = "7"; break;
            case "1000" : number = "8"; break;
            case "1001" : number = "9"; break;
            case "1010" : number = "A"; break;
            case "1011" : number = "B"; break;
            case "1100" : number = "C"; break;
            case "1101" : number = "D"; break;
            case "1110" : number = "E"; break;
            case "1111" : number = "F"; break;

        }
         System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

I need to use loop and a switch op to do the conversion. After making those changes. I get my result of binary 1111 1110 as F then E on the next line. How can I fix that? I don't want to use stringbuilder because I haven't learn that. Is there any other simple code to do that?

Comment: Your loop has no effect at all, as you `return` after the first iteration.

Comment: In addition to that, strings are immutable. `binary.trim()` has absolutely zero effect. You need to do `binary = binary.trim()`.

Comment: Why not use this instead,

`int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binary,2);
String hex = Integer.toString(decimal,16);`

If you do have to implement on your own then follow the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Strings *are* immutable

```
binary = binary.trim(); //not just binary.trim();
```

Also, you'd want to get the string from index 0 to 3, not 0 to 4. So it's `(i, i+3)`

So in here it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i += 4) {
 String num = binary.substring(i, i + 3);
```

Also, take out the return statement at the bottom, because it exits the method when you do one iteration

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is inside your `for` loop, so after the first iteration you will return from the function. Also, you are overwriting `number` at every itteration. You should instead replace `number` with a `StringBuilder` and user `append()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner ms = new Scanner(System.in);

    String binary = ms.nextLine();
    binary.trim();

    //add leading zeroes if length divided by 4 has remainder.
    while (binary.length() % 4 != 0) binary = "0" + binary;

    StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i += 4) {
       String num = binary.substring(i, i + 4);

       switch(num)
        {
            case "0000" : number.append("0"); break;
            case "0001" : number.append("1"); break;
            case "0010" : number.append("2"); break;
            case "0011" : number.append("3"); break;
            case "0100" : number.append("4"); break;
            case "0101" : number.append("5"); break;
            case "0110" : number.append("6"); break;
            case "0111" : number.append("7"); break;
            case "1000" : number.append("8"); break;
            case "1001" : number.append("9"); break;
            case "1010" : number.append("A"); break;
            case "1011" : number.append("B"); break;
            case "1100" : number.append("C"); break;
            case "1101" : number.append("D"); break;
            case "1110" : number.append("E"); break;
            case "1111" : number.append("F"); break;
        }             
        System.out.println(number.toString());
    }
    return;
}
```

Also, others have also mentinoed, your `binary.trim()` does not work as expected, it needs to be `binary = binary.trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem with your code is that you `return` right after printing the first `number`! Remove the `return`, and it will print the other numbers, too.

Also, as noted by Josh, you have to do `binary = binary.trim();`, as `trim()` will *not* alter the string in-place but return a trimmed version of the string.

And finally, note that you could replace most of your code with just this...

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
String s = Integer.toString(n, 16);
System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: or: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));`

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're `return`ing from the first iteration of the loop.

Anyways, **here's the piece of code that does just what you want , convert binary string to hexadecimal**

```
static String binToHex(String binStr){
    while(binStr.length() % 4 != 0){
        binStr = "0" + binStr;
    }
    String hexString = "";
    binStr = new StringBuilder(binStr).reverse().toString();
    for(int index = 0, len = binStr.length(); index < len;){
        int num = 0;
        for(int indexInQuad = 0; indexInQuad < 4; indexInQuad++, index++){
            int bit=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(binStr.charAt(index)));
            num += (bit * Math.pow(2,indexInQuad));
        }
        hexString += Integer.toHexString(num).toUpperCase();
    }
    hexString = new StringBuilder(hexString).reverse().toString();
    return hexString;
}
```

it also saves you the switch statements

just pass it the binary string value and it works seamlessly :D